# renderSectionHeader in ListView

Tags: react-native

I'm new to React Native and was wondering whether there was a cleaner way than using `Object.keys(Object.keys(this.props.sectionData))` to display the text of a header on the child element

```
// Parent

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { ListView } from 'react-native';
import OccurrenceDetail from './OccurrenceDetail';
import ListSection from './ListSection';

export default class OccurrenceList extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    const dataSource = new ListView.DataSource({
      rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2,
      sectionHeaderHasChanged: (s1, s2) => s1 !== s2
    });
    this.state = {
      dataSource: dataSource.cloneWithRowsAndSections([
        { 'Monday':
          [
            {
              startTime: '2012-04-23T18:25:00.000Z',
              endTime: '2012-04-23T19:25:00.000Z',
              customerName: 'Tim Smith',
              address: '68 Hall St, Bondi Beach'
            },
            {
              startTime: '2012-04-23T18:25:00.000Z',
              endTime: '2012-04-23T19:25:00.000Z',
              customerName: 'Tim Smith',
              address: '68 Hall St, Bondi Beach'
            }
          ]
        },
        { 'Tuesday':
          [
            {
              startTime: '2012-04-23T18:25:00.000Z',
              endTime: '2012-04-23T19:25:00.000Z',
              customerName: 'Tim Smith',
              address: '68 Hall St, Bondi Beach'
            },
            {
              startTime: '2012-04-23T18:25:00.000Z',
              endTime: '2012-04-23T19:25:00.000Z',
              customerName: 'Tim Smith',
              address: '68 Hall St, Bondi Beach'
            }
          ]
        }
      ])
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ListView
        dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
        style={styles.container}
        renderRow={(rowData) => <OccurrenceDetail occurrence={rowData} />}
        renderSectionHeader={(sectionData, sectionID) => <ListSection sectionData={sectionData} sectionID={sectionID} />}
      />
    );
  }
}

// Child

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';

export default class ListSection extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text key={this.props.sectionID}>{Object.keys(this.props.sectionData)}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While it's doing the same thing, in terms of "cleaner" I found [this tutorial](https://medium.com/differential/react-native-meteor-oauth-with-facebook-3d1346d7cdb7#.2mj723a60) on ListView population very helpful in streamlining my data formatting. I end up with a constructor:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    const getSectionData = (dataBlob, sectionId) => dataBlob[sectionId];
    const getRowData = (dataBlob, sectionId, rowId) => dataBlob[`${rowId}`];
    const ds = new ListView.DataSource({
      rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2,
      sectionHeaderHasChanged : (s1, s2) => s1 !== s2,
      getSectionData,
      getRowData,
    });
    const { dataBlob, sectionIds, rowIds } = this.formatData(this.props.data);

    this.state = {
        dataSource: ds.cloneWithRowsAndSections(dataBlob, sectionIds, rowIds),
    };
}
```

and then a formatData() function, taken directly from that tutorial:

```
formatData(data) {
    const headings = 'Heading 1*Heading 2*Heading 3*...'.split('*');
    const keys = 'key 1*key 2*key 3*...'.split('*');
    const dataBlob = {};
    const sectionIds = [];
    const rowIds = [];
    for (let sectionId = 0; sectionId < headings.length; sectionId++) {
        const currentHead = headings[sectionId];
        const currentKey = keys[sectionId];
        const collection = data.filter((theData) => theData.type == currentKey);
        if (collection.length > 0) {
            sectionIds.push(sectionId);
            dataBlob[sectionId] = { sectionTitle: currentHead };
            rowIds.push([]);
            for (let i = 0; i < collection.length; i++) {
                const rowId = `${sectionId}:${i}`;
                rowIds[rowIds.length - 1].push(rowId);
                dataBlob[rowId] = collection[i];
            }
        }
    }
    return { dataBlob, sectionIds, rowIds };
  }
```

I have my data object in an outside file and either import it or have it sent in as "props" as in the above. Hope that helps!

Edit: After reading your question again, it seems you're more concerned with how the Text child references the data...so I'm not sure it the above helps or not. My ListView ends up:

```
<View style={styles.container} >
     <ListView  showsVerticalScrollIndicator ={false}
                contentContainerStyle={ styles.listview }
                dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
                renderRow={(rowData) =>
                    <View>
                        <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => this.props.onItemSelected(rowData)}
                                            style={[styles.launcher]}>
                            <Text style={ styles.launcher_text }>{rowData.title}</Text>
                        </TouchableHighlight>
                    </View>
                }
                renderSeparator={(sectionId, rowId) => <View key={rowId} style={styles.separator} />}
                renderSectionHeader={(sectionData) => <MenuSectionHeader {...sectionData}
                 />}
     />
</View>
```

Good Luck!